# Does YouTube Recommendations Use age or Gender?

Tags: youtube, recommendation-engine

I investigate YouTube for educational purpouses and Wanna Look on what Data is used and how its influences the  YouTube Homepage .
So i Made some Experiments with Gender and age , but they have not Shown any Effect.

So Does YouTube not Use this Data?
Or do they recognize Me scraping them ?

Answer (score 1):

That information is only known by YouTube/Google and I doubt they'll share the specifics.

You can, however, read the information available in these sources:

> N.B: These are available information online - by using Google Search
> and for a deep, concrete understanding, you have to read all info
> linked in these and related search results for, example, the topic "how youtube
> recommendations works":

- [How YouTube Works - Product Features, Responsibility, & Impact](https://www.youtube.com/howyoutubeworks/)
- [How Youtube is recommending your next video](https://www.vantage-ai.com/blog/how-youtube-is-recommending-your-next-video)